# Recent site changes that anyone can use

Tags: discussion

The devs are always working on the software that drives this site and all the other stackexchange sites.  There have been a couple recent changes that I wanted to highlight to make sure that everyone is aware of them.

- There is a [review page](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/review).  On this page you can view recent questions and answers that could use more eyes on them.

  - First questions and answers - This is an easy way to help welcome new people to the site.  Take a look at their posts, comment and vote as necessary.  **Please be polite** as we want to ensure that everyone's first impressions of the site are positive.  If you see something that is totally wrong (spam/offensive) then flag it and a moderator will be along shortly.
  - Low quality:  An ongoing metric.  I think this is mainly looking at the length of a post now.  If the post is short, take a look and encourage the poster to flesh it out if you think that is necessary.
  - Late answers: These are new answers to older questions.  Make sure the new answer is really needed
- [Anyone can edit](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/)  I think this is a great change, and the blog post goes into the full detail, but in short

  - Low rep and anonymous users can suggest edits to all questions/answers/tag wikis
  - These go into a queue which higher rep users can view and accept
  - An accepted edit is worth 2 rep, with a max of 1000 gained per user from this function

Please give them a try!